# Why does Peter Pan age in Hook?

Tags: plot-explanation, hook

In the movie [*Hook* (1991)](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0102057/), when Peter finally starts to remember his past, it shows him "running away" from home as a baby younger than a toddler. Unable to walk, talk, etc. Tinkerbell finds Peter in the rain and takes him to Neverland. We then see him return to his family who has forgotten him, and at this point he is around 6 or 7. Then as we see other flashbacks of him visiting Wendy, he is an older adolescent, around 12.

Probably one of the most famous magical qualities of Neverland is that you don't grow old there. So if you don't grow up in Neverland, why/how did Peter grow from a baby to a 12 year old?

NOTE: I'm NOT talking about Peter growing old and becoming a lawyer. He ages before he decides to leave Neverland and that is what I'm curious about.

Comment: Peter Pan was a 'young boy who still has all his first teeth' which in itself would be unusual for an adolescent…but  he had to get to that age somehow. Barrie explained his never ageing further as he 'never wanted to grow up'. Neverland wasn't the source of his lack of ageing, that was a later invention.